# Modify the html of a div which is inside a modal with the contents from ajax response

Tags: jquery, html, ajax

HTML goes like following: Simple Login Form.

```
<div aria-hidden="true" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" class="modal hide fade" id="myModal" role="dialog"
                 tabindex="-1">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button aria-hidden="true" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" type="button">×</button>
                    <h3 id="myModalLabel">Registered Member - Please Login</h3>
                    <div id="login_error"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <form role="form" id="login-form" data-bind="submit: login_user">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="span3">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <div class="input-group">
                                        <input class="form-control" placeholder="name" name="name" type="text"
                                               autofocus>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <div class="input-group">
                                        <input class="form-control" placeholder="Password" name="password"
                                               type="password" value="">
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" type="submit">Sign In</button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Upon form submission a KNOCKOUT JS binding is used to trigger ajax call which should return data.

Java Script code goes like following:

```
this.login_user = function(formElement){
            var formData = new FormData($('#login-form')[0]);
            $.ajax({
                url: 'site_api/user_login.php',
                type: 'POST',
                processData: false,
                contentType: false,
                cache: false,
                data: formData,
                success: function(res)
                {
                    if(res > 0){
                        window.location = "http://r";
                    } else {
                        $('#login_error').html('Invalid Credentials. Please try again.');
                    }

                },
                error: function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError)
                {

                    alert (xhr.status);

                }
            });
        };
```

$('#login_error').html('Invalid Credentials. Please try again.');
This is not working. I am getting correct ajax response but somehow i am not able to set html correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I think id **login_error**  is comes multiple time on the same page . so that both id conflict with eachother. I have made some changes in your code please check it

**Updated HTML goes like following: Simple Login Form.**

```
<div aria-hidden="true" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" class="modal hide fade" id="myModal" role="dialog"
                 tabindex="-1">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button aria-hidden="true" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" type="button">×</button>
                    <h3 id="myModalLabel">Registered Member - Please Login</h3>
                    <div id="login_error" class="login_error"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <form role="form" id="login-form" data-bind="submit: login_user">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="span3">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <div class="input-group">
                                        <input class="form-control" placeholder="name" name="name" type="text"
                                               autofocus>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <div class="input-group">
                                        <input class="form-control" placeholder="Password" name="password"
                                               type="password" value="">
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" type="submit">Sign In</button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
```

**Updated Java Script code goes like following:**

```
this.login_user = function(formElement){
            var formData = new FormData($('#login-form')[0]);
            $.ajax({
                url: 'site_api/user_login.php',
                type: 'POST',
                processData: false,
                contentType: false,
                cache: false,
                data: formData,
                success: function(res)
                {
                    if(res){
                        window.location = "http://r";
                    } else {
                        $('#myModal.login_error').html('Invalid Credentials. Please try again.');
                    }

                },
                error: function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError)
                {

                    alert (xhr.status);

                }
            });
        };
```